# Navigation bar - CSS how to add opacity and hover on a pic next to a text

Tags: html, css, opacity, navigationbar

I've got this problem with my navigation bar menu. I'd like to get an effect for every bar item as appearing picture next to the bar item while clicking hover. So when I point the bar item it shows me an image next to it.
My problem is that the picture shows me only if I'm pointing only on the picture, not whole bar item.

Here's my code. I would be grateful for help. I know the problem must be in CSS.
I also tried `.klik:hover` instead of `.nav-logo:hover, .bar-item:hover` but I came with nothing.

```css
 .bar-item {
    border-color:var(--light-lime);
    color: var(--light-lime);
    background-color:white;
        
    padding: 10px 10px;
    width: fit-content;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.nav-logo {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: auto;
    opacity: 0
}
.nav-logo, .bar-item {
    display:inline-flex;
}
.klik {
    display:inline-flex;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    text-align: left; 
}


.nav-logo:hover, .bar-item:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo" class="dropdown-content">
    <div class="klik">
        <img class="nav-logo" src="images/favicon.png" alt="logo padáku">
        <a href="#pt_about" class="bar-item">about me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="klik">
        <img class="nav-logo" src="images/favicon.png" alt="logo padáku">
        <a href="#pt_studium" class="bar-item">study</a>
    </div>
    <div class="klik">
        <img class="nav-logo" src="images/favicon.png" alt="logo padáku">
        <a href="#pt_prace" class="bar-item">my work</a>
    </div>
    <div class="klik">
        <img class="nav-logo" src="images/favicon.png" alt="logo padáku">
        <a href="#para" class="bar-item">skydiving</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add qualifiers to your CSS after :hover tags, which is what you'll need to do in this case. In your instance, you want the image to show every time you hover over `.klik`, so your code for that line will be as follows:

```
.klik:hover .nav-logo {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This line means, when you are hovering over `.klik`, change the opacity of .nav-logo.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  it works. I will find more about qualifiers :)

Comment: No problem! [Here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.php) is a very helpful resource for that for further reading. Please make sure to mark the answer as correct for future people and upvote if it was helpful, thanks!